# In Sitecore how do I update a large number of placeholder settings that are using dynamic placeholders

Tags: sitecore

For some reason the placeholder key for a large number of pages changed I need to change it back. The problem is we use dynamic place holders so parts of the placeholder key are random GUIDs and they are in every sublayouts placeholder key

So I need

```
/bacontent/../baproducttabscaffold{6e0244e2-3583-47cb-b575-0bc920186d42}
```

to be

```
/bacontent/../baproducttabscaffold{895ecd6f-4abb-478d-9dad-88e5e05b8c30}
```

What would be the most efficient way of changing these?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What I ended up doing is using Sitecore Powershell Extensions
https://marketplace.sitecore.net/en/Modules/Sitecore_PowerShell_console.aspx

The script I used

```
$pages = gci -Path "master:\my path" -Recurse 
$oldGuid = "6e0244e2-3583-47cb-b575-0bc920186d42"
$newGuid = "895ecd6f-4abb-478d-9dad-88e5e05b8c30"

foreach($page in $pages){
    $oldRenderings = $page.__Renderings
    $newRenderings = $oldRenderings.Replace($oldGuid, $newGuid)
    $page.BeginEdit()
    $page.__Renderings = $newRenderings
    [void]$page.EndEdit()
}
```